# Django Rest Framework - use serializers to send json with requests library

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I hava DRF setup that receives data in json and stores it inside django. Serializer is following

```
class ReservationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room = RoomSerializer()
    reserved_days = DaySerializer(many=True)
    additional_services = AdditionalServicesSerializer(many=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [
            'start',
            'end',
            'check_in_time',
            'check_out_time',
            'reserved_days',
            'additional_services',
            'room',
            'has_refund',
            'payed',
            'guest_name',
            'reservation_number',
        ]
```

Can I use this serializer to prepare models in json and then send this json with `Requests` library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *feasible*, if you see the need. Although, the JSON encoding is done in the Response object, which is a full HTTPResponse subclass, so you would need to encode your own data:

```
import json
import requests

my_objects = Reservation.objects.all()
serializer = ReservationSerializer(data=my_objects, many=True)
if serializer.is_valid():
  # now you do your encoding:
  encoded_data = json.dumps(serializer.data)
  response = requests.post(your_url, 
                           headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                           data=encoded_data)
```

Comment: not working with passing and validating data. but works if pass my_objects directly to serializer without data validation